# Grouping by and ordering by an aggregate column

Tags: reporting-services

I'm creating a SSRS report and  have the following data set.

```
ID       City      Country
------------------------------
1       London     England
2       Glasgow    Scotland
3       Aberdeen   Scotland
4       Swansea    Wales
5       London     England
6       Glasgow    Scotland
7       Glasgow    Scotland
8       Manchester England
```

I have a `COUNT` on the 'City' and grouped by City and Country. This is how I would like it to appear

```
City              Country              Total
--------------------------------------------
Glasgow           Scotland               3
London            England                2  
Swansea           Wales                  1
Aberdeen          Scotland               1
Manchester        England                1
```

However, this is how it's appearing

```
City               Country             Total
--------------------------------------------    
Swansea           Wales                  1
Glasgow           Scotland               3
                                         3
                                         3
Aberdeen          Scotland               1
Manchester        England                1
London            England                2
                                         2
```

So I need to group by the aggregate total column and also order by that column but not sure how to do it. All help appreciated, thanks.

Have tried Sanjays answer below, unless I'm doing it wrong I'm getting this error.

[image]

Comment: For your new error, it looks like you put the **Sort** expression on the **Table** and not on the **Group**. You can only use aggregate funtions at the Group level. Go to the Group Properties and add the Sort there (right-click on your Group and click **Row Group** --> **Group Properties**) and remove it from the table. The **Group** property pop-up looks the same as the **Table** property.

Comment: Thanks Hannover, you were right I was putting the sort expression on the table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here
we need to create city and country as group and delete detail section from row groups as like below

[image]

so table look like after above changes

[image]

and set **Count(Fields!ID.Value,"CITY")** sd sorting expression for first group city1 with order Z to A

[image]

Comment: Here my group expression is on group column not on table I have attach in image clearly. So you may right click on group expression and set sort expression.

Comment: Thanks Sanjay, this does work, I was doing it incorrectly

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple ways you could go about this. One option would be to handle the grouping in the query and simply display the results in SSRS. So your query would look something like this:

```
SELECT ID, City, Country, COUNT(*) as Total
FROM MyTable
GROUP BY ID, City, Country
```

Now in SSRS you can sort by the `Total` column since it's not being aggregated in the report.